# How do I translate an android keyEvent's keycode to something that Robot can use on a desktop machine?

Tags: java, android, awt, keypress

As the question states, I wish to translate android keycodes to java awt keycodes that `java.awt.Robot` can use in its `keyPress()` and `keyRelease()` methods.

The mapping is different in the two, is there a library that provides a translator? Or do I have to research the mapping charts and hardcode them in myself >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me too, I have been wondering why Android does not follow ASCII.

I made a hardcode too, but it's a bit concise, hope that helps:

```
public static int toAscii(int key) {
  if (key >= KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A && key <= KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z)
    return key - KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A + 'A';
  else ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am starting to just hardcode it:

```
private int translateKeyCode(int keyCode)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
        case AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_0:
            return KeyEvent.VK_0;
        case AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_1:
            return KeyEvent.VK_1;
        case AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_2:
            return KeyEvent.VK_2;
        case AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_3:
            return KeyEvent.VK_3;
        // 300 miles more of this stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: To say it more concisely, the answer to the question is: no, there's no easy way to just plug in a library.  Robot is kind of fatally flawed that way really.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.getUnicodeChar()` method. `event` is an object of `KeyEvent` class.

```
int asciiKey = event.getUnicodeChar(event.getMetaState());
```